# Why does a constructor of an object return Object() instead of its constructor?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

This question is purely of academic value.

Given a constructor function `Foo()`:

```
function Foo(){
    this.x = 1;
}
```

and an instance of that class:

```
var o = new Foo(); // Instance of Foo()

console.log(o.constructor); // => Foo(): The constructor of `o` is `Foo()` - this makes sense so far.
```

But, if I set the prototype property of `Foo()` constructor manually...

```
Foo.prototype = { z: 3};

var o = new Foo(); // Instance of Foo()
```

`o`'s constructor becomes `Object()`, so not `Foo()`:

```
console.log(o.constructor); // => Object {}
```

I get that `Foo()` (o's constructor's `prototype` property) is changed, but isn't the constructor of an instance of `Foo()` still  `Foo()`? Isn't it the `prototype` property **of** Foo() that is changed, not Foo() itself?

Comment: The `.constructor` property of which you're asking isn't a magic property. It's an ordinary property that is assigned by default to every function's prototype object and points back to the function. When you replace the default prototype object of the function, you're getting rid of that default `.constructor` property.

Comment: So to paraphrase for my understanding, `o` gets its constructor property by inheriting it from `Foo.prototype.constructor`? And thus by overwriting `Foo.prototype` with an object like `{}`, `o` instead inherits that object's constructor property and thus returns `Object()` as the constructor instead of `Foo()`. Is that correct?

Comment: I guess the missing link for me was the fact that `o.constructor` is inherited from `Foo.prototype.constructor`. I for some reason assumed that  `o.constructor` was an own property of any JS object, not an inherited one from its constructor's `prototype` property.

Comment: That's correct. And to be clear, the new object you assign to `Foo.prototype` inherits its `.constructor` from `Object.prototype`, so the property is now inherited from `o -> Foo.prototype -> Object.prototype.constructor`

Answer (score 2):

A constructor is nothing else than a simple function. Any function is a constructor.

The real and sole magic is in the [new operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) : it's that operator which creates a new instance of the given "class".

Quoting the MDN :

> When the code new foo(...) is executed, the following things happen:
>
> - A new object is created, inheriting from foo.prototype.
> - The
>   constructor function foo is called with the specified arguments and
>   this bound to the newly created object. new foo is equivalent to new
>   foo(), i.e. if no argument list is specified, foo is called without
>   arguments.
> - The object returned by the constructor function becomes the
>   result of the whole new expression. If the constructor function
>   doesn't explicitly return an object, the object created in step 1 is
>   used instead. (Normally constructors don't return a value, but they
>   can choose to do so if they want to override the normal object
>   creation process.)

Note the order : you don't apply `new`  to `Foo()` but to `Foo`. That's why you can also write

```
var o = new Foo;
```